# WordPress / 固定ページテンプレート内のコードのショートコード化

Tags: php, wordpress

舞台公演の情報を表示するページを作成しております。

カスタムフィールドで入力した内容を取得して一覧表示させるコードを作成し、
”固定ページのテンプレートに記述して表示”させることには成功しました。

これを**スタンダードな投稿記事の中でも同様に表示させたい**と考え、
**ショートコードにして呼び出す**という方法で実現を試みているのですが、
function.phpに同様の内容を記述し、ショートコード化する記述を追加したところうまく動作せず（表示が真っ白になってしまう）、どのようにすればよいかつまづいています。

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、どこに問題があるのか、どのようにするとうまくいくのか、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
<p style="font-size:80%;display:inline-block;width:auto;padding:3px 15px;margin:20px 0 0 0;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid #ddd;">
2018年4月
</p>

<?php
$posts = get_posts(
               array(
                 'numberposts' => -1,
                 'post_type' => 'kouen',
                 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                 'meta_key' => 'schedule_start',
                 'order' => 'ASC',
                 'meta_query' => array(
                   'key' => 'schedule_start',
                   'value' => array('2018/04/01','2018/04/31'),
                   'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                   'type'=>'DATE'
                 )
              )
             );

global $post;
?>
<?php if($posts): foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>



<div style="padding:15px 0;border-bottom:1px dotted #dddddd;line-height:140%;">

<span style="font-size:90%;">
<?php $week = array("日", "月", "火", "水", "木", "金", "土"); ?>
<?php $date = date_create(''.get_field('schedule_start').''); echo date_format($date,'n月j日') . "(" . $week[(int)date_format($date,'w')] . ")" ; ?>
〜
<?php $date = date_create(''.get_field('schedule_end').''); echo date_format($date,'n月j日') . "(" . $week[(int)date_format($date,'w')] . ")" ; ?>
</span>
<br>
<span style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;">
<strong>
<?php the_field('team_name'); ?>『<?php the_field('title'); ?>』
</strong>
<span style="font-size:80%;"><?php the_field('location'); ?></span>
</span>

<!--URlがあれば表示、の分岐　ここから-->
<?php $imgid = get_field('url'); ?>
<?php if(empty($imgid)):?>
<?php else:?>
<span style="font-size:80%;margin-bottom:10px;display:block;">→&nbsp;<a href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('url'); ?></a></span>
<?php endif;?>
<!--URlがあれば表示、の分岐　ここまで-->

<!--感想1があれば表示、の分岐　ここから-->
<?php $imgid = get_field('kanso1_title'); ?>
<?php if(empty($imgid)):?>
<?php else:?>
<!--<span style="font-size:90%;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;">観劇レポート</span>-->
<span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;">・<a href="<?php the_field('kanso1_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('kanso1_title'); ?></a></span><span style="font-size:90%;">　by<?php the_field('kanso1_user'); ?></span><br>
<?php endif;?>
<!--感想1があれば表示、の分岐　ここまで-->

<!--感想2があれば表示、の分岐　ここから-->
<?php $imgid = get_field('kanso2_title'); ?>
<?php if(empty($imgid)):?>
<?php else:?>
<span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;">・<a href="<?php the_field('kanso2_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('kanso2_title'); ?></a></span><span style="font-size:90%;">　by<?php the_field('kanso2_user'); ?></span><br>
<?php endif;?>
<!--感想2があれば表示、の分岐　ここまで-->

<!--感想3があれば表示、の分岐　ここから-->
<?php $imgid = get_field('kanso3_title'); ?>
<?php if(empty($imgid)):?>
<?php else:?>
<span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;">・<a href="<?php the_field('kanso3_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('kanso3_title'); ?></a></span><span style="font-size:90%;">　by<?php the_field('kanso3_user'); ?></span><br>
<?php endif;?>
<!--感想3があれば表示、の分岐　ここまで-->

<!--感想4があれば表示、の分岐　ここから-->
<?php $imgid = get_field('kanso4_title'); ?>
<?php if(empty($imgid)):?>
<?php else:?>
<span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;">・<a href="<?php the_field('kanso4_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('kanso4_title'); ?></a></span><span style="font-size:90%;">　by<?php the_field('kanso4_user'); ?></span><br>
<?php endif;?>
<!--感想4があれば表示、の分岐　ここまで-->

<!--感想5があれば表示、の分岐　ここから-->
<?php $imgid = get_field('kanso5_title'); ?>
<?php if(empty($imgid)):?>
<?php else:?>
<span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bold;">・<a href="<?php the_field('kanso5_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('kanso5_title'); ?></a></span><span style="font-size:90%;">　by<?php the_field('kanso5_user'); ?></span><br>
<?php endif;?>
<!--感想5があれば表示、の分岐　ここまで-->


<!--見る見た表示　ここから-->
<?php
 $cfcb = get_field_object('mirumita');
 $cfcbId = get_post_meta($post->ID,'mirumita');
 $cfcbId = $cfcbId[0];
 if($cfcb) {
 foreach($cfcbId as $v) {
 echo '<span style="font-size:60%;" class="ico-'. $v. '">' . $cfcb['choices'][$v] .'</span>';
 }
 }
 ?>
<!--見る見た表示　ここまで-->


      </div><!--data_box-->

<?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Comment: single（投稿記事）ので動かすなら安易にsingleで使っている変数を変更してはいけない（変数$postなど）また、'if{ foreach() {'　で始めたなら 閉じる時も'} }'に統一した方が良いと思います。wp-configdeデバッグモードを有効にして”define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );”何処でエラーになっているか確認して見ましょう。

Comment: 上のコメント'if{ foreach() {'ところ訂正　'foreach():'と'foreach() {'が混在しているのどちらかに統一した方がよいかと思います。